# Org-mode and visual-line-mode except in tables

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Is there a way to turn off *visual-line-mode* within Emacs [Org-mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Org-mode) tables?

I very much like how *visual-line-mode* works in Org-mode, except when it wraps wide tables, making them unreadable.

Maybe seven years ago, Carsten Dominik (Org-mode founder) asked the Emacs maintainers for line-by-line control of *visual-line-mode*, and he indicated that he got a positive response.  Did that get implemented, and has anyone put it to use for Org-mode tables?

Comment: There are at least two (2), and perhaps three (3) threads dedicated to this issue.  The answer is that you cannot mix and match `truncate-lines` and `word-wrap` in the same buffer.  You could get really fancy with some tricks, but no one has taken the time to implement it -- probably because of performance issues and no one is sufficiently motivated (so far) to take on the challenge.  If you search for the above-mentioned variables and something like `org-mode` and `tables`, the other threads should come up with a quick Google search.  You could even throw in my username to find the threads.

Comment: I use `word-wrap` when I edit a task/event/subtree, in an indirect buffer, and I return to `truncate-lines` once I'm done editing the task/event/subtree.

Comment: Checking in almost 7 years later -- is this still not possible without a third-party package?

Answer (score 1):

There is the [phscroll](https://github.com/misohena/phscroll) which uses overlays around org-table to make this work.

[image]
([via](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/62523))